# Magento Category Url error: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: magento-1.9

Getting following error on one of my category url, need help. How do I fix this

Magento Commerce
    There has been an error processing your request
    SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

```
Trace:
#0 /home/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(56407): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(56963): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55076): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(56133): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(57071): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(30817): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(30748): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php(141): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_setup')
#8 /home/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php(234): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->__construct('core_setup')
#9 /home/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21370): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#10 /home/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21296): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#11 /home/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}

Error log record number: 1120556696777

Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright © 2017 Magento Inc.
```

Comment: did you try to change category url and test it ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are too many MySQL connections and requests coming simultaneously then this situation occurs. Because sever unable to handle such bulk requests at a time. So in this case you can either increase the number of concurrent processes your server is handling to it's maximum value and the server capacity too.

Try this steps:

> 1) Open your mysql configuration file located at /etc/my.cnf
>
> 2) Locate this variable max_connections
>
> 3) Set your desire number of available connection number for avoiding
>   future error max_connections = 250
>
> 4) Restart you mysql server